# How can I get the participant information in a Zoom meeting?

Tags: python

In an online meeting I want to export the participants' information (such as name, email, etc.) as text or another file format I can use in Python. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Your first place to start would be the [Zoom API documentation](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to do this would be via the zoom api.
You can see the documentation for the relevant endpoint here: [zoom docs](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/meetings/pastmeetingparticipants).

To utilise that api in python you would want to make a http request. The requests library is simple to use and is well documented. [requests docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Alternatively you could attempt to use a library that will handle some of this for you such as: [zoomus](https://github.com/prschmid/zoomus). An example from the zoomus documentation doing most of what you want:

```
import json
from zoomus import ZoomClient

client = ZoomClient('API_KEY', 'API_SECRET')

user_list_response = client.user.list()
user_list = json.loads(user_list_response.content)

for user in user_list['users']:
    user_id = user['id']
    print(json.loads(client.meeting.list(user_id=user_id).content))
```

then finally you would want to write the results of your call to a file, which is easily done in python like so:

```
f = open("test.txt", "a")
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

note that you will need to be authenticated to make a request as per the zoom documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is not correct posted by @axwr  It lists the meetings that the user can see, not the meeting participants

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).